# Adding testing stage into Jenkins file

Tags: python, django, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to add Testing stage into my Jenkins file.

I have docker installed in the Jenkins.

I run my tests with this command:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py test
```

This is my Jenkins file:

```
node{
    stage('Checkout'){
        def dockerHome = tool 'docker'
        env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin"
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Build image') {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']){
            sh "docker login --username=mygituks --password=mdj1646MDJ"
            sh "docker build -t my_git_uks -f Dockerfile ."
            sh "docker tag my_git_uks gituks/uks-git-2019:second"
        }
    }
    stage('Run Tests') {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']){
            def testsError = null
            try {
                sh "docker-compose run web python manage.py test"
            }
            catch(err) {
                testsError = err
                echo "Failure"
            }
        }

    }
    stage('Push image') {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']){
            sh "docker push gituks/uks-git-2019:second"
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:
  docker-compose: command not found

This is one of the things I also tried and I get this error:
test.sh: line 3: python: command not found

I added test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

python manage.py test
```

And changed my Testing stage to:

```
 stage('Run Tests') {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']){
            def testsError = null
            try {
                sh "bash test.sh"
            }
            catch(err) {
                testsError = err
                echo "Failure"
            }
        }
```

Hope someone can help me to figure this out or give my any hints.

**SOLVED**

```
node{
    stage('Checkout'){
        def dockerHome = tool 'docker'
        env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin"
        PATH = "$PATH:/usr/bin"
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Build image') {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']){
            sh "docker login --username=mygituks --password=mdj1646MDJ"
            sh "docker build -t my_git_uks -f Dockerfile ."
            sh "docker tag my_git_uks gituks/uks-git-2019:second"
        }
    }
    stage('Run Tests') {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']){
            echo "PATH is: $PATH"
            sh "docker exec my_git_web python manage.py test"
        }

    }
    stage('Push image') {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']){
            sh "docker push gituks/uks-git-2019:second"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you don't have docker-compose installed on your agent.

You can either:

1. Install docker-compose on the agent: (taken from [docker official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)`)

```sh
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

2. Try to use a [Docker with Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) and use

```
docker.image("docker").inside() {
  sh "docker-compose run web python manage.py test"
}
```

Comment: I have solved it already. I have just added it on the post :)

Thanks for the help :)